# Turn SELECT into DELETE mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a heck of a time turn this SELECT statement into a DELETE.

```
$query  = "
SELECT n.thread_id
     , n.status
     , n.status_tooltip_text 
  FROM newmessages n
     , oldmessages o
 WHERE n.thread_id = o.thread_id 
   AND n.status_tooltip_text = o.status_tooltip_text
";
```

The end result I am trying to achieve is to delete from newmessages where the status tooltip text is the same as the status tooltip in oldmessages.

The select I have above works, but when I turn the select into a delete it says database query failed.  The columns in the two tables have identical column definitions.

Comment: I think you'll need something like `DELETE FROM newmessages where thread_id IN( Select n.thread_id FROM newmessages n, olmassages....the rest of your query)`

Comment: Show us your DELETE statement?

Comment: Or you can try `DELETE n FROM .....` and then the rest of your query

Comment: I am still getting a "database query failed" error.  If mysql does not find any rows to delete, would this give me an error?

Comment: Here is the delete statement I have:         $query  = "DELETE FROM newmessages where thread_id IN(";
                $query .= "SELECT n.thread_id FROM newmessages n, oldmessages o ";
                $query .= "WHERE n.thread_id=o.thread_id ";
                $query .= "AND n.status_tooltip_text=o.status_tooltip_text ";
                $query .= "AND n.status=o.status)";

Answer (score 1):

Replacing SELECT with DELETE is not going to work DELETE statement doest not have the column

```
$query  = "DELETE n FROM 
newmessages n, oldmessages o ";
$query .= "WHERE n.thread_id=o.thread_id ";
$query .= "AND n.status_tooltip_text=o.status_tooltip_text";
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

```
$query  = "DELETE FROM newmessages where thread_id in ";
                $query .= "(SELECT thread_id FROM oldmessages ";
                $query .= "WHERE oldmessages.thread_id=newmessages.thread_id ";
                $query .= "AND oldmessages.status_tooltip_text=newmessages.status_tooltip_text ";
                $query .= "AND oldmessages.status=newmessages.status)";
```

Comment: That is one ugly query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to see what's wrong with the following:

```
DELETE n 
  FROM newmessages n
  JOIN oldmessages o
    ON n.thread_id = o.thread_id
   AND n.status_tooltip_text = o.status_tooltip_text
```